# utc date or just a timestamp from right now

Tags: php, date

I have the following code
     **$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00', strtotime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i')) + 0));**
Its doing some utc conversion. Also adding a 0 at the end is kinda confusing too. Also date and gmdate is kinda confusing.
The echo of above is 1328083200
is that a time? a date stamp? how would I convert that back

Comment: What you're getting there is a UNIX timestamp. I don't really understand what your other questions are. Also, this code is terrifically convoluted. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: it was given to me...trying to make sense outta it

Comment: Well, it doesn't make much sense... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime( $string )` will convert the provided `$string`, if in a recognised format, into a UNIX timestamp. A UNIX timestamp is the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch, which is 00:00:00 on 1 January 1970 (UTC).

It appears that the code you have provided is trying to return the UNIX timestamp for the very start of the current day (UTC), hence the `gmdate()`. The 0 at the end is probably a hacky attempt to ensure that an integer is returned, even if it is zero.

See the PHP Documentation for these functions:

- [gmdate()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)
- [strtotime()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
- [date()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

It's cludgy and hacky, but I think you could shorten the existing code down to:

```
$time = strtotime(gmdate('Y-m-d 00:00'));
```

I only offer this as, sometimes, and for unknown reasons (I personally blame gremlins) crazy code like this is crazy for a reason...

Comment: so what is it giving me? Is it giving me 12:00 AM of the current day?

Comment: Yep, like I said "...return the UNIX timestamp for the very start of the current day (UTC)..." So, if, due to time differences, your local date is 2 Jan, but the date at Greenwich is 1 Jan, it will return the Unix Timestamp for 00:00am 1 Jan (not 00:00am 2 Jan, which would be the start of your local day).

Comment: hmm..wonder why would someone wanna do that. That could possibly cause a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's echoing a Unix time stamp. Use [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert it